# python twisted simple server client

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, twisted

I am trying to build a simple "quote of the day" server and client modified from the twisted tutorial documentation.  I want the "quote of the day" to be printed from the client to prove the communication.  However, from what I can tell the client is not connecting.  Here is my code.

Server

```
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ServerEndpoint
from twisted.internet import reactor

class QOTD(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write("An apple a day keeps the doctor away\r\n") 
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class QOTDFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return QOTD()

# 8007 is the port you want to run under. Choose something >1024
endpoint = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8007)
endpoint.listen(QOTDFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Client

```
import sys
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint

class SimpleClient(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        log.msg("connection made")
        #self.transport.loseConnection()

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print "receive:", line

class SimpleClientFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return SimpleClient()

def startlog():
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

point =  TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, "localhost", 8007)
d = point.connect(SimpleClientFactory)
reactor.callLater(0.1, startlog)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- pass instance of SimpleClientFactory, not the class itself to `point.connect()`
- subclass SimpleClient from twisted.protocol.basic.LineReceiver instead of Protocol if you use `lineReceived`
- call addErrback on the results of `endpoint.listen` and `point.connect` to handle errors

Comment: It was subclassing from LineReceiver that made it work.  Thanks!